# Nested If Statement issue, adding third statement brings semantic error

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am needing to add a third IF statement below, which replaces blank values with a 0.
On its own it works fine, the other two IF statements work without this third being added.

How do I correctly insert this third IF statement, as it stands I get a semantic error saying 'Too many arguments passed, 3 is the maximum'

```
RETURN
IF(
ISBLANK( SliderValue ),0, SliderValue,
IF( SliderValue > 0, ProjRR,
IF(SliderValue = 0, Actual)
)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with the first IF, the nested IF (in the fourth row) is the 4th argument
Your code returns 0 when the `SliderValue` is blank and otherwise it returns `SliderValue`, IF is the 4th argument here
The code below is correct syntax wise, but I'm not sure it will return what you expect, can you elaborate what you're trying to achieve?

```
RETURN
    IF (
        ISBLANK ( SliderValue ),
        0,
        IF ( SliderValue > 0, ProjRR, IF ( SliderValue = 0, Actual ) )
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

Am so sorry for the first answer I gave. I thought it was PHP,
try this one out

```
RETURN    
      IF(ISBLANK (SliderValue), 0, IF(SliderValue > 0, ProjRR, IF(SliderValue = 0, Actual)))
```

Comment: This question is about the [DAX language](https://dax.guide/) which does not have an "elseif" function.